# Rendering list using map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Whenever I try to accept or reject a transaction from my notifications section, that particular transaction is supposed to be deleted from the notifications and processed according to the button clicked. But here, the last transaction always gets processed, even though if I have clicked on some other transaction.
I guess there is some mistake in the map function that I used to render the notifications.
The code goes here:

**Notification.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import NavbarComponent from "./NavbarComponent";
import { Card, Button, Modal } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";
import { clearCache } from "clear-cache";

function Notifications({ username }) {
  const [showAccept, setShowAccept] = useState(false);
  const [showReject, setShowReject] = useState(false);

  const [response, setresponse] = useState([]);
  const handleCloseAccept = () => setShowAccept(false);
  const handleShowAccept = () => setShowAccept(true);

  const handleCloseReject = () => setShowReject(false);
  const handleShowReject = () => setShowReject(true);
  const [notifications, setnotifictions] = useState([]);
  const [password, setpassword] = useState("");
  var user = {
    username: username
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchnoti = async () => {
      await axios
        .post("/api/getnoti", user)
        .then((res) => {
          setnotifictions(res.data);
          console.log(res.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    };

    fetchnoti();
  }, []);

  function accept(index) {
    console.log(index);
    var param = {
      noti: notifications[index],
      password: password
    };
    axios
      .post("/api/accepttxn", param)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        setresponse(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  function reject(index) {
    var param = {
      noti: notifications[index],
      password: password
    };
    axios
      .post("/api/rejecttxn", param)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        setresponse(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  const notis = notifications.map((noti, index) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Card>
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Text>Sender: {noti.info.sender}</Card.Text>
            <Card.Text>Amount: {noti.info.amount}</Card.Text>
            <Card.Text>
              {noti.info.message ? (
                <div>Message: {noti.info.message}</div>
              ) : null}
            </Card.Text>
            <Button
              variant="primary"
              onClick={() => {
                handleShowAccept();
                setresponse([]);
                setpassword("");
              }}
            >
              Accept
            </Button>
            <div>
              <Modal show={showAccept} onHide={handleCloseAccept}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                  <Modal.Title>Enter Password to Proceed</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    value={password}
                    onChange={(event) => setpassword(event.target.value)}
                  />
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                  <Button
                    variant="secondary"
                    onClick={() => {
                      handleCloseReject();
                      clearCache();
                    }}
                  >
                    Close
                  </Button>
                  <Button variant="success" onClick={() => accept(index)}>
                    Proceed to Accept
                  </Button>
                  {response}
                </Modal.Footer>
              </Modal>
            </div>
            <Button
              variant="danger"
              onClick={() => {
                handleShowReject();
                setresponse([]);
                setpassword("");
              }}
            >
              Reject
            </Button>
            <div>
              <Modal show={showReject} onHide={handleCloseReject}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                  <Modal.Title>Enter Password to Proceed</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    value={password}
                    onChange={(event) => setpassword(event.target.value)}
                  />
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                  <Button
                    variant="secondary"
                    onClick={() => {
                      handleCloseReject();
                      clearCache();
                    }}
                  >
                    Close
                  </Button>
                  <Button variant="danger" onClick={() => reject(index)}>
                    Proceed to Reject
                  </Button>
                  {response}
                </Modal.Footer>
              </Modal>
            </div>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {notis.length ? <div>{notis}</div> : <h1>No new notifications</h1>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Notifications;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: You can even make it easier for people to help you by doing a **runnable** MRE using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).